# How to set graph escapement in powerbuilder with code

Tags: powerbuilder

I have power builder graphs in my application and i want the user to change escapement from front end of application.

Answer (score 1):

From the PB help file entry on 'escapement':

> In scripts
>   Escapement takes an integer value that specifies the rotation in tenths of a degree. 0 is horizontal. A value of 900 rotates the text 90 degrees; 450 rotates the text 45 degrees. The following example sets the rotation of the Value Axis Label to 90 degrees:
>
> gr_1.Value.LabelDispAttr.Escapement = 900

So you would need some sort of input the user can manipulate and then apply their chosen value to the graph as mentioned above.